# Azure DevOps NPM Cache Not Matching

Tags: angular, npm, caching, azure-devops

I have caching setup in Azure Dev Ops for my Node Modules, it was working fine, but it has seemingly randomly stopped working correctly in one of my apps. When the NPM Cache step runs it outputs the following:

```
Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
Fingerprint: \`npm|"Windows_NT"|---------------------------------2dPPpMMy5Q=\`
```

Later in the Post-job: NPM Cache it outputs the following:

```
Resolving key:
 - npm                                [string]
 - "Windows_NT"                       [string]
 - D:\a\1\s/app/package-lock.json [file] --> ---------------------------------FF1E9956A35F9431D19483B2791A486
Resolved to: npm|"Windows_NT"|---------------------------------MSOLgTMsIA=
##[warning]The given cache key has changed in its resolved value between restore and save steps;
original key: npm|"Windows_NT"|---------------------------------2dPPpMMy5Q=
modified key: npm|"Windows_NT"|---------------------------------MSOLgTMsIA=

ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session ---------------------------------ad8
Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
Fingerprint: `npm|"Windows_NT"|---------------------------------MSOLgTMsIA=`
There is a cache hit: `npm|"Windows_NT"|---------------------------------MSOLgTMsIA=`
Used scope: ---------------------------------b942a8b;refs/heads/dev;---------------------------------.git
Cache with fingerprint `npm|"Windows_NT"|---------------------------------MSOLgTMsIA=` already exists.
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 1 events with X-TFS-Session ---------------------------------ad8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure none of your build steps between the `Cache` and `Post-Job Cache` step change the cache key value.

For instance, we use the below value as the cache key for our NPM example.

`npm | $(Agent.OS) | ${{ parameters.WORKING_DIR }}/package-lock.json`

So let’s say there is a `npm publish` step in the build which changes the value of `package-lock.json`. In this case, you’ll never get a cache hit because `package-lock.json` (hash) is part of the unique cache key.

> There are two workarounds — either remove the change causing step or
> remove `package-lock.json` from the key.

Check this documentation:

https://medium.com/tenets/azure-pipeline-caching-a53e8117c242

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm not sure that I have anything that would be doing that as I only do an npm install if the cache is not hit and then I do an npm run with the following being the script `node --max_old_space_size=8000 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=dev --baseHref=/ --output-hashing=all --aot`

Comment: You could set variable `system.debug` to `true`, to see whether there is more inforamtion.

Answer (score 2):

The message "The given cache key has changed in its resolved value between restore and save steps" might be because the package-lock.json file was generated with a different node/npm version than your pipeline is using.

I had a similar problem today and resolved it by updating my local versions of node/npm to match my pipeline versions

Comment: This helped me realize that my local environment was building a package-lock.json file that differed from the pipeline. Not sure how my local package-lock.json file was being built - some VS helper command built it. But running `npm install` from command line and pushing the change to the repo fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to cache the `npm install` step of a build or validation pipeline is with explicit dependencies in your `package.json` file. So no `^` or `~` before the version to specify minor or patch release updates.

This is because `npm install` does not respect your `package-lock.json` file. It automatically updates any dependencies based on the semvers in your `package.json`. This means you can't have your cache key be a hash of your `package-lock.json`, since it will just get updated by the subsequent `npm install` step, and your hashes will constantly be different (let alone the fact that you're updating dependencies in a pipeline, and not before, while developing).

npm attempted to solve this with the `npm ci` command-- ci standing for "clean install". This installs *only* what's listed in your `package-lock.json` file, which is great. But, as the name suggests, it also deletes all of your node_modules and installs them again, defeating the purpose of any previous cache.